# get person id through authenticated user id

Tags: python, django

I try to get person id of my Person model, connected with User model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


    class Person(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

        def __str__(self):
            return '%s %s %s' % (self.user.last_name, self.user.first_name, self.middle_name)
```

from template-generated page, but I only can get user id who authenticated right now

```
{{ user.id }}
```

but not Person id.

How can I get Person id through user id on the page?

Comment: Django gives you a reverse lookup on foreign keys, so you should be able to do {{ user.person.id }}

Comment: @Joseph: since a `Person` points to a `User`, but not with a unique constraint, a `User` can be related to *multiple* `Person`s, hence the reverse will be `user.person_set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django automatic reverse lookup foreign key (user field) from an model, if you want to get person id try this `{{user.person.id}}`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest OneToOneField for this kind of relation.

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

then you can use `user.person`

Comment: This is the best answer (in regards to mine), however this is assuming you only want 1 person per user. (Normally you do)

Comment: Thanks... yes.. normally one person has only one user and vice versa right?

Comment: Well unless you are allowed to have multiple people with one user. Like you could do something like, 1 business account (user) that has 5 people on it (Person). I am not necessarily saying that is the best way, but that could occur. The 5 person could just be a reference to employees that this 1 user keeps track of. (Employees aren't actually involved). But I still think this is best answer, we dont know what he is going for that's why I gave him what he wanted below and suggested 1:1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having logical issue with your model. One person generally should have connected with one user so you should user `OneToOneField` instead of `ForeignKey`. Let's think you are correct then you can follow the code below, if you are not then it will work too.
You can get it through context variable 
Suppose your `person=Person.obejcts.get(id=1)`
Then pass it through context in view like

```
def view(request):
    person=Person.obejcts.get(id=1)
    context = { 'person':person}
   return render(request, 'your.html', context}
```

And in template you can use `{{person.id}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `{{ user.person_set.get(pk=1) }}` . This assumes you know the pk...if you only actually store 1 person with 1 user, then substitute the `.get()` with a `.first()` ...you can access your foreign key model using the `main_obj.fk_obj_set.all()` and do things just like any other queryset. This obviously assumes you have multiple users for 1 person..otherwise things get easier with a 1:1 field.